# Facebook Group API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I want to build a small app, which helps people to learn the names of members of any facebook group they are part of (simular to a vocabulary trainer). Therefore I want to access the images and names of people in a group, but I have problems understanding the Facebook API-Documentation for Groups.

The [Documentation says](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/group/):

- Public groups can be accessed with any token (but I also want to access not public groups)
- user_managed_groups permission can be used to read the group content for a group in which the user is an admin (But what if the user is not the admin, just a normal member?)

So is there no way to access the group members of a closed group by using the User Access Token of a not-admin facebook user, even that he normaly would be able to see this information using the website or app?

Comment: That is correct. Just because they can see something on Facebook.com doesn't mean it is available in the API.

Comment: _“even that he normaly would be able to see this information using the website or app?”_ – http://stackoverflow.com/a/37921035/1427878